# Android - Getting a list of nearby places

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-now

I need to be able to get a list of nearby places within my app. I want this to be inside a NavigationDrawer as well. Just like Google Now's Nearby Places card:

[image: Google Now card]

Although I want this to be wrapped inside a NavigationDrawer. Any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Google Places API is a web-based sevice, so you need to send a request to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json
  ?location=COORDINATES_IN_LAT_LONG
  &radius=DISTANCE_IN_METERS
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

The result you will get back will be in JSON which is fairly easy to parse using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.79593620000001,
               "lng" : -122.40000320
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.80475270,
                  "lng" : -122.38399580
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.78711860,
                  "lng" : -122.41601060
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
         "id" : "7498697d87cb1a28280277cb7825e0a4c21387d6",
         "name" : "Financial District",
         "reference" : "CoQBegAAAFrgJ9ZyeZrV_a9QWteNl9hrNGq-9qhPIP0M9yIL00HhKzBJNERhX95nEnAAtgBKqc2e51Yq2-OG3g-D8YZ20pcFKK7n3Pipd3Rpz7JmFedlg-gimYv3YGhOYVhblHYhhJM8y48J7tbDT4QPKsnumhsyhTf-5YktikanlFKt3NKNEhDwKmUyXRDhsYS1-rzHCZSRGhQP5VmDcuvvxvYE7e7dC-0PWYhfjw",
         "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ],
         "vicinity" : "San Francisco"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.7856560,
               "lng" : -122.4012520
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/art_gallery-71.png",
         "id" : "5e693f5ae4f1cd1512732b1568ff0e4b67ab0291",
         "name" : "San Francisco Museum of Modern Art",
         "rating" : 4.30,
         "reference" : "CpQBgQAAAO9fVOGklWz3ugJeJ0DuVibD60yFJ_z19hm5Cm7f4NYsIECaVqC2yhQ746w2vMmAJmA-jYNNwp5_ot7hsRxVmcbO1TdvBtYG3LZ6JD2vxgMXSCFK3U2McAywoOsbPwjU-9fN6jtHmvuiCXNDamIUP4IX462NsmyO06digENJcMoLES75jTTvVBjuRvNFRdIJnRIQDtf7lhNra8eTmAYy1PKKnhoU7hDZ-Y6TB8HRnHBsVDnsWnL5E0o",
         "types" : [ "art_gallery", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "151 Third Street, San Francisco"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.7791590,
               "lng" : -122.4158080
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/library-71.png",
         "id" : "b1c83827c82c9fa59ffcdad652d1e8a1b04a4ae8",
         "name" : "San Francisco Public Library",
         "rating" : 4.20,
         "reference" : "CoQBewAAAP-wCLLWVV2kys-vTPPr9LZPUkZXqrUUjG6LTRmcVARlehuh_SkvisDlH5X6WgoX6BG16e7RSS94xxhZbj0B3i7gC1KFDz_Oc88hK6YUj3w8Ix0N5M6UmKfAIXq1CYXLMrt_KAR7WsNF65MiSnj-Nqu0AMxwW-dMvRfmHOk7xGW0EhCyRZgNzYmPV08XAHZ-HBx_GhQYlLxuAU4MH8FvkdMWbQ1Xvf7WxA",
         "types" : [ "library", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "100 Larkin Street, San Francisco"
      },
```

You can then pass it to the adapter of your navigation drawer, if you so choose. If you want to show this data in the navigation drawer even in offline mode, cache this data in a `txt` file and read it on starting the app. This will also have the added advantage of saving bandwidth by refreshing this data only when the user chooses so.

If you want places ranked by distance, add `&rankby=distance` to your request URL.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/places/training/)

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to implement this into an app?

Comment: That will be fairly long but look at `HttpURLConnection`, `URL` classes to make the request and GSON to deserialize the text.

Comment: Is there a free alternative?